# How to use tensorflow js in wecaht mini app web worker?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want to use tensorflow js in wechat mini app. And I also wanto to use web worker in wechat mini app to improve performance.

but, I find if I import tensorflow js in worker index js, console will print `[worker] Uncaught Error: Could not find a global object`.

How should I to fix it?

TensorFlow.js 3.5.0
tfjs-wechat plugin 0.0.6
WeChat IDE 1.06.2210310 (M1 Arm)

step to reapper:

`package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection": "^0.0.3",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.5.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^3.5.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.5.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu":"^3.6.0",
    "abab": "2.0.0",
    "base64-js": "1.3.1",
    "fetch-wechat": "0.0.3",
    "text-encoder": "0.0.4"
  }
```

1. npm install & use build npm
   [image: build npm]

**we need to remove the tr46 package, otherwise the program will not be compiled by the applet**

2. prepare workers file

I do this as doc describe: https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/workers.html

3. copy the miniprogram_npm to workers/request dir
4. edit workers/request/index.js like this:

```js
const tf = require('./miniprogram_npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/index')

worker.onMessage(res => {
    console.log("worker 收到的 res: ", res)
})
```

5. send message to worker in app.js

```js
    const worker = wx.createWorker('workers/request/index.js')
    worker.postMessage({
        msg: "hello"
    })
```

then the work will report `[worker] Uncaught Error: Could not find a global object`.

but if we add `tr46` package in `workers/request/miniprogram_npm`, the work will compile error because heap memory overflow. like this:

[image: out of memory]

Comment: I have worked with WeChat mini program and i think there are some limit than normal web, you may need to update the source of TensorFlow to work inside WeChat. i will need to install WeChat IDE and test

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply! you can test like question to reappear (I edit it again)